# Click Event On Every Item Of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have Five Items in listview and five activities and now i want to open 
my single acitivity on click the single item of listview means Actvity1 should
be open on clicking item1, Activity2 should be open on clicking item2,
Activity3 should be open on clicking item3.
please tell me how can i do this.

Thank you

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to do this. Try Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding conditions inside `onItemClick` method of `OnItemClickListener` based on the position of the item in `ListView`:

```
 ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
             if (position == 0) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Activity1.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
             }
             else if (position == 1) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Activity2.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
             else if (position == 2) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Activity3.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
             } 
             else if (position == 3) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Activity4.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
             } 
             else if (position == 4) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Activity5.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
             } 
       }

   });
```

Comment: thanks bro its helpful for me

Comment: Great, if it help, can you accept the answer.

Comment: yes sure but sorry don't know how do this bocause i am new in this community

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: ok i have done.....thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position from the OnItemClickListener as below :

```
  ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // position 0 -> activity one

        }
    });
```

or you can assign a tag value for each row and check it using view.getTag();

Hope this will help.